# Cloudera Manager Failed to authenticate: issue with ssh key

Tags: hadoop, ssh, cloudera

I'm trying to test Cloudera installation using a 2 node cluster with a user `testuser` which has sudo rights.
I generated ssh keys for each node using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and made sure to copy `id_rsa.pub` of each node to the other's `.ssh/authorized_keys` i.e. node1 has node2's pub key in `authorized_keys` and node2 has node1's pub key in `authorized_keys`

But when I copied node1's `id_rsa` into Cloudera and run the Cloudera Manager installation, Cloudera is able to authenticate node2 but fails to authenticate node1, and similarly when I copy node2's `id_rsa` into Cloudera, Cloudera authenticates node1 but fails to authenticate node2
Where am I wrong and which of the `id_rsa` am I supposed to use?

Comment: Check permissions of the keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put master's private key into .ssh/authorized_keys of all nodes, including that of master's.